# VBA, copy and paste lots of rows in another worksheet with a criteria

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Well, I'm a newbie in VBA so I'm asking for some help. So I have a file from an experiment with a lot of data. Basically, I have 21 steps of measurements and for each step N points are recorded. Every steps are on one worksheet and I can spot them with the word "step".
For each step I want to copy the N points and send them to another sheet, I wrote a macro but nothing happen except creating a new sheet. You can have a look on my code below:

```js
Sub mymacro()

Worksheets("laos").Activate
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Byte
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add

With Worksheets("laos")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For n = 1 To LastRow
    With Worksheets("laos")
            If .Cells(n, 1) = " step " Then
                For i = 1 To 9763 'N points recorded
                .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A" & i)
                Next
            End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What did you intend to accomplish with this line: `If .Cells(n, 1) = " step " Then`

Comment: Are you looking for "step"?  or " step "?  because the spaces will matter

Comment: I don't understand where the N points are recorded?  Are they in columns on "laos"?  Could you put a screenshot of the Laos page?  It will help.  I don't understand where you got the value 9763 for your i Loop.

Comment: have look below, I tried to answer to your questions

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking to do if I understood your original post, which I probably didn't.  More details about the layout of your sheets would help.  This concept is probably enough though to teach you what you are seeking.  Look at the screenshots provided to understand the layout.

In this example, you already have created the target sheet.  You just need to make header rows, and name the sheet, then when you declare the variable newSheet = "WHATEVER YOU NAMED THAT SHEET"  in this example, it's "TargetSheet"

```
Sub mymacro()
'Declare the counters as Integers, not byte
Dim oRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastNewRow As Integer
Dim newSheet As String
Dim nRow As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim LastNCol As Integer
Dim searchString As String

'Not Sure what kind of value the N points are.
Dim Value As String

'The original sheet is Sheets("laos"
'If you don't need to create the new Worksheet every time, just declare it.
newSheet = "TargetSheet"

'set LastRow using by specifying the sheet and range to search.
LastRow = Sheets("laos").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
LastNewRow = Sheets(newSheet).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Sets the destination Row on the newSheet
nRow = 2

'oRow = Original Row.
For oRow = 2 To LastRow

    'This is looking to Row# N:, Column A for the value = "step" contained in the text
    'If the InStr (InString) function returns a value greater than 0 meaning "step" occurs
    searchString = Sheets("laos").Cells(oRow, 1)
    If InStr(searchString, "step") > 0 Then

        'Assuming you have to loop through N points, Find the last column of the STEP row.
        LastNCol = Sheets("laos").Cells(oRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Label the new Row
        Sheets(newSheet).Cells(nRow, 1) = Sheets("laos").Cells(oRow, 1)

        'start loop with 2 for ColumnB
        For n = 2 To LastNCol
        'Copy the VALUE from the original sheet, and set the new sheet with it.
        Value = Sheets("laos").Cells(oRow, n)
        Sheets(newSheet).Cells(nRow, n) = Value

        Next n

        'Since we are done copying all the N Points to the New Row, we increment the nRow + 1
        nRow = nRow + 1

    'Must END IF
    End If

Next oRow

End Sub
```

[image: laos Sheet]
[image: Target Sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I wasn't very accurate and I don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot of my worksheet.So I got Sine Strain measure with N points recorded (in my code N=9763 but it can change), and there are 22 Sine Strain (or step). Everything is on the same worksheet. At the end, I want to have one sine strain per sheet (I don't care about the name of the different sheets).

I hope It will be useful for you.

I'll try to do something with your code.